# How to get the confidence interval of a Weibull distribution using Python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, confidence-interval, weibull

I want to perform a probability Weibull fit with 0.95% confidence bounds by means of Python. As test data, I use fail cycles of a measurement which are plotted against the reliability R(t).

So far, I found a way to perform the Weibull fit, however, I still do not manage to get the confidence bounds. The Weibull plot with the same test data set was already performed with origin, therfore I know which shape I would "expect" for the confidence interval. But I do not understand how to get there.

[image: example for confidence interval]

I found information about Weibull confidence intervals on [reliawiki](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/The_Weibull_Distribution)(cf. Bounds on Reliability based on Fisher Matrix confidence bounds) and used the description there to calculate the variance and the upper and lower confidence bound (R_U and R_L).

Here is a working code example for my Weibull fit and my confidence bounds with the test data set based on the discription of [reliawiki](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/The_Weibull_Distribution) (cf. Bounds on Reliability). For the fit, I used a OLS model fit.

```py
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import math
import statsmodels.api as sm

def weibull_ticks(y, pos):
    return "{:.0f}%".format(100 * (1 - np.exp(-np.exp(y))))

def loglog(x):
    return np.log(-np.log(1 - np.asarray(x)))

class weibull_example(object):

    def __init__(self, dat):
        self.fits = {}
        dat.index = np.arange(1, len(dat) + 1)
        dat.sort_values('data', inplace=True)
        #define yaxis-values
        dat['percentile'] = dat.index*1/len(dat)
        self.data = dat

        self.fit()
        self.plot_data()

    def fit(self):
        #fit the data points with a the OLS model
        self.data=self.data[:-1]
        x0 = np.log(self.data.dropna()['data'].values)
        Y = loglog(self.data.dropna()['percentile'])
        Yx = sm.add_constant(Y)
        model = sm.OLS(x0, Yx)
        results = model.fit()
        yy = loglog(np.linspace(.001, .999, 100))
        YY = sm.add_constant(yy)
        XX = np.exp(results.predict(YY))
        self.eta = np.exp(results.params[0])
        self.beta = 1 / results.params[1]
        self.fits['syx'] = {'results': results, 'model': model,
                            'line': np.row_stack([XX, yy]),
                            'beta': self.beta,
                            'eta': self.eta}

        cov = results.cov_params()
        #get variance and covariance
        self.beta_var = cov[1, 1]
        self.eta_var = cov[0, 0]
        self.cov = cov[1, 0]

    def plot_data(self, fit='yx'):
        dat = self.data
        #plot data points
        plt.semilogx(dat['data'], loglog(dat['percentile']), 'o')
        fit = 's' + fit
        self.plot_fit(fit)

        ax = plt.gca()
        formatter = mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(weibull_ticks)
        ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
        yt_F = np.array([0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5,
                         0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99])
        yt_lnF = loglog(yt_F)
        plt.yticks(yt_lnF)

        plt.ylim(loglog([.01, .99]))

    def plot_fit(self, fit='syx'):
        dat = self.fits[fit]['line']
        plt.plot(dat[0], dat[1])

        #calculate variance to get confidence bound
        def variance(x):
            return (math.log(x) - math.log(self.eta)) ** 2 * self.beta_var + \
                   (self.beta/self.eta) ** 2 * self.eta_var - \
                   2 * (math.log(x) - math.log(self.eta)) * (-self.beta/self.eta) * self.cov

        #calculate confidence bounds
        def confidence_upper(x):
            return 1-np.exp(-np.exp(self.beta*(math.log(x)-math.log(self.eta)) - 0.95*np.sqrt(variance(x))))
        def confidence_lower(x):
            return 1-np.exp(-np.exp(self.beta*(math.log(x)-math.log(self.eta)) + 0.95*np.sqrt(variance(x))))

        yvals_1 = list(map(confidence_upper, dat[0]))
        yvals_2 = list(map(confidence_lower, dat[0]))

        #plot confidence bounds
        plt.semilogx(dat[0], loglog(yvals_1), linestyle="solid", color="black", linewidth=2,
                 label="fit_u_1", alpha=0.8)
        plt.semilogx(dat[0], loglog(yvals_2), linestyle="solid", color="green", linewidth=2,
                 label="fit_u_1", alpha=0.8)

def main():
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.set_xlabel("$Cycles\ til\ Failure$")
    ax1.set_ylabel("$Weibull\ Percentile$")

    #my data points
    data = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1556, 2595, 11531, 38079, 46046, 57357]})
    weibull_example(data)

    plt.savefig("Weibull.png")
    plt.close(fig)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The confidence bounds in my plot look not like I expected. I tried a lot of different 'variances', just to understand the function and to check, if the problem is just a typing error. Meanwhile, I am convinced that the problem is more general and that I understood something false from the description on [reliawiki](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/The_Weibull_Distribution). Unfortunately, I really do not get what's the problem and I do not know anyone else I can ask. In the internet and on different forums, I did not find an appropriate answer.

That's why I decided to ask this question here. It's the first time I ask a question in a forum. Therefore, I hope that I explained everything sufficiently and that the code example is useful. 
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the very late answer, but I'll provide it for any future readers.
Rather than try implementing this yourself, you may want to consider using a package designed for exactly this called *reliability*.
Here is the [example](https://reliability.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Fitting%20a%20specific%20distribution%20to%20data.html#example-1) for your use case.

Remember to upvote this answer if it helps you :)